# Qt Quick: Putting Repeater and standalone item in GridLayout leads to weird behavior

Tags: qt, layout, qml, grid-layout, qtquick2

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 6
        Repeater {
            model: 7
            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
        }
        //Rectangle {color: "red"; width: 20; height: 20}
    }
}
```

It shows this:

[image: screenshot]

Which is fine.

But when you uncomment the line containing `color: "red"`, the layout breaks:

[image: screenshot]

Any idea why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: Does it need to be with hardcoded values ? If you place `Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true;` into your red rectangle, it would look like the others

Comment: You declared your rectangle with a specific values. So I suspect, that this caused the columns to be defined with these values, because size of a column usually depends on its items. Since the blue rectangles in the repeater are using `Layout.fill*`, they filled the columns with those red rectangle values, leading to this behavior. On the other hand, you also declared `anchors.fill: parent` which contradicts the alignment of your columns, so one column filled the rest. Well, that is what I think, not sure if thats all right.

Comment: @DuKes0mE: Hmm, indeed placing `Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true;` into the red rect fixed it. Weird, I thought I tried that. Ok, that's half of the problem solved, thanks :) . Now what remains is the question *why* the problem happens. "You declared your rectangle with a specific values." - yeah, but I declared it small, yet its cell became the largest in the layout. "which contradicts the alignment of your columns" - not sure what you mean by alignment here, and I don't see the contradiction.

Comment: What I meant was, that the property `Layout` adapts it size automatically, comparing the size of an item (e.g. a rectangle) and the remaining space. If you don't use hard-coded values, everything works fine, but once you setup values, the Layout adapts to those. Which means, every other rectangle also adapts to these values and has a width and height of 20 in this case. But if every rectangle were that small, there would be tooo much space left, since the GridLayout has set anchors to fill its parent. So the GridLayout will "dynamically" allocate the rest of the space to the last items.

Comment: And the last items are in the same row/column of the item which caused the layout break.

Comment: @DuKes0mE: Could you point me to a reference on Layout using the size set on a *single* item for all the other items? It seems like very strange behavior if it's true. Also, I tried setting the red rect to have size 50x50 to see if the blue rects grew to this size too, but they didn't - they became smaller instead.

Comment: In any case `Repeater` has nothing to do with the issue at hand. It's a layout issue.

Comment: Uh, isn't that what the `Repeater` is for ? You set the width and height of the items just once there and they are applied to all items. Alternatively, you can wrap an `Item` around the red rectangle. That way, the item can apply the `Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true;` while the red rectangle has the hard-coded size. Effectively, you would only see the red rectangle, since `Item` would stay as an invisible placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's causing your issue, because I haven't tested it out, but you [should avoid](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#details) setting the `width` and `height` of items that are managed by a `Layout`:

> Note: It is not recommended to have bindings to the x, y, width, or height properties of items in a layout, since this would conflict with the goals of Layout, and can also cause binding loops.

You should use `Layout.preferredWidth` instead of `width`, for example.

For more information, see [Specifying Preferred Size](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-overview.html#specifying-preferred-size).

Comment: Thanks, what you said makes sense, but I tried setting `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.preferredHeight` without setting `width`, `height`, `Layout.fillWidth` and `Layout.fillHeight` and the problem is still there. So apparently for the layout to work right I need the `Layout.fill*` stuff.

Comment: @StefanMonov I think the layout is trying to do it's best to arrage stuff and since the only `Item` with an explicit `width`/`height` is the last one, it arranges stuff according to that. It should have checked that the first row has no explicit `width` set in any `Item` but apparently it is not doing such a check. If you add `Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / grid.columns` to the blue rectangle you indeed get the correct sizing for `width`. I would say a bug report is worth the effort here.

Comment: Having tried out the example now, I'd also suggest filing a bug report. I'd be interested in knowing if this is a valid issue or not. It seems like it should work.

Comment: @ Mitch with next to no knowledge of the implementation it seems to me that this is a bug, much like the one of some months ago, i.e. the `item`s incorrectly resizing when only `fill*` properties were set. Writing code to arrange stuff can be tricky, especially if you cannot foresee all the scenario. Anyhow, @StefanMonov I've created [QTBUG-58583](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58583).